# React app goes into infinite loop when typing into a form-type Component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

My React app with a Rails API backend goes into a non-ending loop when I start typing out information into a form for inputting new info. The form is rendered by the following component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { getToken } from '../redux/actions/auth';
import axios from 'axios';

const AddCreation = () => {
  const { reset } = useForm();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [creation, setCreation] = useState({});
  const { currentUser } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);

  if (currentUser.role !== 'admin') {
    navigate('/');
  }

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    setCreation({ ...creation, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    console.log(creation)
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData();
    const img = document.getElementById('art_image');

    data.append('image_url', img.files[0]);
    // data.append('journeyman_id', parseInt(id, 10));
    data.append('artist', creation.artist);
    data.append('title', creation.title);
    data.append('type_of_work', creation.type_of_work);
    data.append('medium', creation.medium);
    data.append('dimensions', creation.dimensions);
    data.append('date_of_composition', creation.date_of_composition);
    data.append('art_category', creation.art_category);
    data.append('comment', creation.comment);
    data.append('price', creation.price);
    
    axios.post('http://localhost:3001/v1/creations', data, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        Authorization: getToken(),
      },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        navigate('/');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    reset();
  };

  return (
    <main className="">
      <div className="my-5 d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
        <h2>Add a Creation to Listing</h2>
        <form className="my-5 d-flex flex-row justify-content-center border border-dark" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="my-5 mx-5">
            
            <div className="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between my-3">
              <label
                className=""
                htmlFor="artist-name"
              >
                Artist Name:
              </label>
              <input
                className=""
                id="artist"
                type="text"
                name="artist"
                onChange={handleChange}
                required
              />
            </div>
            

... continues like so with the other inputs, until ...

            <div className="my-3">
              <button className="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" >
                Add Creation
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
};

export default AddCreation;
```

This is the error message I obtain as soon as I start typing anything into the form:

```
react_devtools_backend.js:2655 Warning: Cannot update a component (`BrowserRouter`) while rendering a different component (`AddCreation`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `AddCreation`, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render
```

This is the way things are routed in App.js

```
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import ProtectedRoutes from './components/ProtectedRoutes';
import useAuth from './hooks/useAuth';
import Signup from './components/Signup';
import Login from './components/Login';
import Creations from './components/Creations';
import AddCreation from './components/AddCreation';

function App() {
  const { authChecked, loggedIn } = useAuth();

  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login loggedIn={loggedIn} />} />
        <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
        <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes isAllowed={loggedIn} authChecked={authChecked} redirectPath="/login" />}>
          <Route path="/creations" element={<Creations />} />
          <Route path="/" element={<AddCreation />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have tried to change the routing in App.js to the following:

```
<Route element={<ProtectedRoutes isAllowed={loggedIn} authChecked={authChecked} redirectPath="/login" />}>
  <Route path="/creations" element={<Creations />} />
  <Route path="/add-creation" element={<AddCreation />} />
</Route>
```

This gets rid of the loop problem but then the form is unable to call up the API on the backend. A series of console.log confirms to me that the form is passing it's values on, so the problem does not reside in that aspect.

Comment: were you able to see if there was a response from the rails backend (error or success) from your axios call?

Comment: I can't even get to test the connection to the API that is being called up because the infinite loop doesn't allow me to input all the info for the request. I did, however, test the backend directly (that is, without the intervention of the React-Redux front-end app) using "Postman" and everything was in order.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is the `navigate` function called as an unintentional side-effect in the component body of `AddCreation`. Move this into a `useEffect` hook if you must check any auth/role status in a routed component. You will also not want to redirect back to the same route the user is already on. Redirect to `"/login"` or some other safe non-admin route.

Example:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  if (currentUser.role !== 'admin') {
    navigate("/login", { replace: true });
  }
}, [currentUser.role, navigate]);
```

This should probably be abstracted into a route protection component similar to the `ProtectedRoutes` component.

Comment: Thank you very much Drew. The issue of the infinite loop got resolved thanks to your suggestion.

Comment: I got rid of the problems for which I originally posted, Drew, now I am having to figure out why my component isn't reading the role for the current user (in fact, any of the current user data) after the app has allowed me to log in. But all this is a matter for another post. Thanks again.

Comment: @German Welcome, and glad to hear that the initial render looping issue is resolved. Cheers.